# Monte Carlo dart simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x, montecarlo

I've been trying to make a dart simulator using the Monte Carlo simulation in Python 3. So far, I have written the following code:

```
import random
import math

n = (input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
count = 1
circleval = 0
squareval = 0
while count <= n:
    y = 2*random.random()*2-1
    x = 2*random.random()*2-1
    if math.sqrt((x-1)**2+(y-1)**2)<=1:
        circleval+=1
        squareval+=1
    else:
        squareval+=1
    count+=1

print("Pi is " + 4*(1.*circleval/squareval))
```

However, when I run this I reccive the following error message:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: what error do you encounter?

Comment: `n = (input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))`  gives you a string, you probably want to convert to `int`, e.g.: `n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))`

Comment: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: After I do that, convert it to int, I get this error. File "Untitled 12.py", line 18, in <module>
    print("Pi is " + 4*(1.*circleval/squareval))
TypeError: must be str, not float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason why this does not work is because:

```
n = (input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
```

will put a string into `n`, we can solve this with:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
```

and:

```
print("Pi is " + 4*(1.*circleval/squareval))
```

expects a string, but you do not provide one, we can solve this with:

```
print("Pi is " + str(4*(1.*circleval/squareval)))
```

But that being said, the program is still incorrect: it gives `0.773` as output for Pi, which is clearly wrong.

The main problem is your sampling: you want to generate numbers between -1 and 1, but you generate numbers between -1 and 3. In your distance computations, you then use `x-1` and `y-1` shifting it to the -2 to 2 domain, but that is still too large. Furthermore the code not very elegant.

```
from random import random

n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
c = 0
for i in range(n):
    x = 2*random()-1
    y = 2*random()-1
    if x*x + y*y <= 1:
        c += 1
print("Pi is %s" % (4.0*c/n))
```

for `n=100000`, this has given me `3.14368` (although it might vary of course between several simulations).

Comment: @Blake McLaughlin this should be the accepted answer since Willem is also explaining the problem with the implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I just checked back, I've been trying to alter variable n to be a for loop so I can have a long range of outputs for what pi is equal to. Sorry for not giving you credit immediately, that was my bad, thank you for the corrections!

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

```
n = input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
```

should be:

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
```

(since you want to treat `n` as an integer)

and

```
print("Pi is " + 4*(1.*circleval/squareval))
```

should be:

```
print("Pi is " + str(4*(1.*circleval/squareval)))
```

Since you can't add a string to a number

Other than that - I'm not sure if the calculation is correct - but that would be another issue.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try inputting this into the original code.

Comment: It worked well, thanks for the help. As dumb as it sounds In kept trying to put the string after the print statement before asking the question. Thanks for the fix alfasin.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the string-to-int issues already identified, you might find this simpler if you set your `x` and `y` bounds to `[-1,1]`.
Also, consider using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))
count = 1
circleval = 0
squareval = 0
while count <= n:
    y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1)
    x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1)
    if np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) <= 1:
        circleval+=1
        squareval+=1
    else:
        squareval+=1
    count+=1

print("Pi is", 4*(1.*circleval/squareval))
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of darts you have. 1000000
Pi is 3.142168
```

Notes:
- You don't need to keep track of `squareval`, you can just use `n`.
- You can use Numpy's vectorized operations to skip the `while`-loop:

```
area = 4
n = int(input("Enter the number of darts you have. "))

X = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n)  
Y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=n)   

dist = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2);  

in_circle = np.sum(dist < 1.0)

print("Pi is", area * in_circle/n)
```